# how to replace "(double quotes) in a string with \" in java

Tags: java, string, replace, str-replace

I have string variable strVar with value as `' "value1" '` and i want to replace all the double quotes in the value with `' \" '`. So after replacement value would look like `' \"value1\" '`

How to do this in java?
Kindly help me.

Comment: Does your code compile? is `' "value1" '` what you see in the source code or what you see when you print it out?

Answer (score 58):

You are looking for

```
str = str.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/KG9bTR)

I would avoid using `replaceAll` since it uses regex syntax which you don't need and which would complicate things since `\` as also special character in regex for:

- `target` describing *what* to replace,
- `replacement` (where `\` is special character used to escape other special character `$`).

In other words to create `replacement` representing `\` we need to escape that `\` with another `\` like `\\`.

BUT that is not the end since `\` is also special character in String literals - for instance we can use it to escape `"` like `\"` or to create special characters like tabulation `"\t"`.
So to represent `\` in String literal we also need to escape it there by another `\` like `"\\"`.

This means, to represent `\` in `replacement` we need to escape it twice:

- once in regex syntax, `\\` -> `\`
- and once in string literal `"\\\\"` -> `\\`

So code using `replaceAll` could look like:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\""); 
//replacement contains `\\\\` to represent `\`, and `\"` to represent `"`
```

or if we want to let regex engine handle escaping for us:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\""));
```

With `replace` method we don't need to worry about regex syntax and can focus only simple text. So to create String literal representing `\` followed by `"` all we need is `"\\\"`.

Answer (score 11):

actually it is:
    `strVar.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");`

Answer (score 6):

For example take a string which has structure like this--->>>

```
String obj = "hello"How are"you";
```

And you want replace all double quote with blank value or in other word,if you want to trim all double quote.

Just do like this,

```
String new_obj= obj.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are formatted with double quotes. What you have is single quotes, used for `char`s. What you want is this:

`String foo = " \"bar\" ";`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want;

```
System.out.println("'\\\" value1 \\\"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

**To replace double quotes**

```
str=change condition to"or"      

str=str.replace("\"", "\\"");
```

After Replace:change condition to\"or\"

**To replace single quotes**

```
str=change condition to'or'      

str=str.replace("\'", "\\'");
```

After Replace:change condition to\'or\'