# Android edittext: How to display the data inserted in edittext in a separate activity programmatically?

Tags: java, android

The screen shot of my problem is provided in this link:

https://goo.gl/photos/24BTZMX1DxLXnm5J9

I am using two separate activities, for example activity A and activity B. In activity A, I have incorporated an edit text field. If the user enters some characters within double quotations, I have to display only the characters that are mentioned inside the double quotations.

For example, if the user input in the edittext is like

Value = "Welcome to the restaurant"

It has to display **Welcome to the restaurant** in the activity B, by neglecting **Value=**

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance
Save Our Souls.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Comment: Do you want to remove the double quotes or pass the content to next activity?

Comment: are the double quotation supposed to be always first and last of the sentence, or they may appear anywhere in the sentence and you want to remove all appearance of the double quotations?

Comment: @ajantha I need to pass the characters presented inside the double quotes and to display it in the seperate activity.

Comment: @rahul the double quotes is presented anywhere in the sentence and I want to display the things inside the double quotes alone.

Comment: see this. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299788/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-a-string-with-in-java

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please, import to your post the linked image.

Comment: @ajantha... thanks I will look into it and let you know

Comment: @Hector since I am a newbie here, It is asking for 10 reputations to import my image here ;-)

Comment: In the future the image link could be broken and your question would lose quality.

Comment: @Hector Yes I agree bro ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Keeping in mind your sentense  *I want to display the things inside the double quotes alone.*)

```
    String example="Value = \"Welcome to the restaurant\""; //replace with EditText value

    int firstQuoteIndex=example.indexOf("\"")+1;
    int lastQuoteIndex=example.lastIndexOf("\"");

    String result=example.substring(firstQuoteIndex, lastQuoteIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks brow. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks a tonne bro! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. in activity A

   ```
   String usertext= edittext.getText().toString();
   ```

2.

```
Intent i =new Intent(A.this,B.class);
i.putExtra("uservalue",usertext);
startActivity(i);
```

3.
In B activity

```
String valueretrn=getIntent().getExtra().getString("uservalue");
textview.setText(valueretrn);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know.