# Replace all " characters to \" Java

Tags: java, string, replace

How replace all `"` characters with `\"`. I have some String, like this:

> {"ConfirmId":"0d8de6a6-15f1-4084-ba3a-4ebfe3151b38","Amount":1.00,"Fee":0.00,"FullAmount":1.0}

And I need something like this answer:

> {\"ConfirmId\":\"0d8de6a6-15f1-4084-ba3a-4ebfe3151b38\",\"Amount\":1.00,\"Fee\":0.00,\"FullAmount\":1.0}

How can I do this?
This is example of my part of code:

```
String replace = Answer.get(1);
replace = "\"" + replace.replaceAll("\"","\\\"") + "\"";
System.out.println(replace);
```

But it doesn't work nice. Have somebody any idea?

Comment: replace.replaceAll('"', '\\"')

Comment: What means: `But it doesn't work nice`?

Comment: "But it doesn't work nice." => What do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299788/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-a-string-with-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line to following

```
replace = replace.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

It will change "Confimed" to \"Confimed\"