# Replace " in Java String to Get Integer value from it

Tags: java, android, string, replace, double-quotes

I have a **String/Value** `"2.450,00`. I want to get the **Integer** value from it. For that, I need to remove the `"` in front of the `2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386107/how-to-remove-single-character-from-a-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299788/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-a-string-with-in-java

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Java - removing first character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503656/java-removing-first-character-of-a-string).

Comment: str.replace("\"",""); will not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

First you want to remove the comma sign and the decimals since an int (Integer) is a whole number.

```
str = str.split(",")[0];
```

This will split the string on the "," and take the first index which contains the string "2.450". Then you want to remove the punctuation. This can be done by replacing everything which is not a number with an empty space "".

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Lastly, you want to convert the string to an integer.

```
int strAsInt = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The initial value
    String str = "2.450,00";

    str = str.split(",")[0];

    str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

    int strAsInt = Integer.parseInt(str);

    // This will print the integer value 2450
    System.out.println(strAsInt);
}
```

One liner:

```
int stringAsInt = Integer.parseInt(str.split(",")[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet. Use substring method to remove "

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "\"2.450,00";

  // prints the substring after index 1 till str length
  String substr = str.substring(1);
  System.out.println("substring = " + substr);

}
```

Comment: You could also just omit the second argument as it will default to the end of the string.

Comment: Yes we can do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to remove any non-digit character *(excluding the `'.'` and `','` characters)* from the input string, the regex `"[^\\d\\,\\.]"` may help you with this:

```java
final String inputString = "Total: 100.000,05$";
final String numberString = inputString.replaceAll("[^\\d\\,\\.]", "");
```

The next step is a formatting digit string into a valid `double` form. At this step, you'll need to replace `'.'` with an empty string and the `','` with a dot `'.'`.

```java
final String formattedNumberString = numberString
                                      .replace(".","")
                                      .replace(',', '.');
```

And, in the end, you are finally able to parse a valid number:

```java
double inputNumber = Double.parseDouble(formattedNumberString);
```

Answer (score -1):

(1) Remove double quote from string

```
String str = "\"2.450,00";

str = str.replace("\"", "")
```

(2) then you should replace the comma as well

```
str = str.replace(",", "")
```

(3) Finally you should use the 
Integer.parseInt() method to convert String to Integer

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
```